# Embedded resource file throws file not found exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, embedded-resource

I am embedding a resource in a custom assembly for localization. My asp page will generate images with localized text on it.

After deploying my application in IIS, it works fine for a few hours. But, later it throws a "FileNotFoundException" for my resource file and images are not rendered too.

After recycling the application pool, everything works fine again also issue starts again after a few hours.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: It sounds like IIS is not ever freeing the resource it loaded for you, and eventually runs out of room to load any more copies of it.  Can you monitor memory/resources/etc during those hours to see what is going on? (google "Process Monitor" if you don't already know tools for this).

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was resource file naming- it seems it cannot contain more that one dot: resource.en-us.zip is bad, but resource-en-us.zip is fine

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below url. Maight be it will be helpful.

[Assembly resources FileNotFoundException in project upgraded to VS 2010 framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734009/assembly-resources-filenotfoundexception-in-project-upgraded-to-vs-2010-framewor)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114997/Embedding-and-Using-Resources-from-Net-Assembly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In link 1, this exception was thrown from the begining, but in my case it occurs after a few hours when refreshing the page. Link 2 explains about creating an embedded resource file. I'll edit my scenario in more detail.