# c# : Program fails to load *project*.resources; FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I inherited the source code for a program our company uses, written in C# / .NET 3.5.  It is a large solution (60+ projects) so if you need code posted, you'll have to ask, as I'm not sure what to post.

I'm getting `FileNotFound` exceptions when it attempts to load the dll libraries. The errors are all related to libraries built within the solution (fellow projects).  But it's looking for `*project*.resources.dll` where there are only `*project*.dll` and I don't know why.  I'm confused if there is missing resources, or something else.  I believe it only started happening since I upgraded the solution to .NET 4.6, but I don't know this for certain.

To be clear, it builds, compiles, and runs. It throws exceptions which I can see in the debug log, and also appears in the `Assembly Binding Log Viewer`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the stack trace:

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: Did you try changing your forms' `Localizable` property to `false`?

Comment: There's stuff in the .resx file, which I think I need.  That would eliminate the resources files right?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Can you access those resources even when you get the exception?

Comment: This user was upgrading from 3.5 to 4.0 and had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/9209972/1826081

Comment: @HebeleHododo I saw that earlier, but I tried that and I still got the errors.  The error does say "or one of it's dependencies".. Does this mean that I would have to do this for all of them to do a true test?

Comment: Hmm maybe. Do you have a lot of assemblies? You could try all of them, if it's manageable. Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: @HebeleHododo I added the stack trace.

Comment: Well, don't just blindly resolve assemblies if you don't have them.  It is probably looking for a way to localize the app, you don't show enough of the stack trace to tell.  If you pass null then it uses the default localization.

Comment: I do have the assemblies.  It's looking for *.resources which is what it can't find.

Comment: @HebeleHododo You were right.  It was the same problem the other user had.  It must have been a dependency thing.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @beardedmogul I'm glad I was able to help.